# Make a Leaflet Tooltip draggable

Tags: leaflet

I have got the following tooltip:

```
var tooltip = L.tooltip()
.setLatLng(latlng)
.setContent('Hello world!<br />This is a nice tooltip.')
.addTo(map);
```

Now it it fixed (it does not move). Is it possible to make it draggable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tooltip `.getElement()` method to get tooltip DOM element and then make it draggable with the `L.Draggable` class (see https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#draggable).

Code to make tooltip dragable could then look something like this:

```
var tooltip = L.tooltip({permanent: true, interactive: true})
  .setLatLng(latLng)
  .setContent('Hello world!<br />This is a nice tooltip.')
  .addTo(map);
var tooltipElement = tooltip.getElement();
var draggable = new L.Draggable(tooltipElement);
draggable.enable();
```